# Limits, continuity and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

I require some assistance for part ii) of this question, particularly the section I have highlighted in green. I would have thought that even if $g$ is not continuous at $a$ it could still be the limit as ${h \to 0}$?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The limit argument for $f'$ does not make any appeal to the value of $g(a)$, only that the limit $\lim_{h \to 0} g(a+h)$ exists. So $f'(a) = g(a)$ if and only if $g(a)$ equals the limit (since that is what $f'(a)$ is equal to), in which case $g$ is continuous at $a$.